# JQuery Dialog Focus of OK button On Load

Tags: jquery, jquery-dialog

I am using JQuery UI dialog for validation alert message and it's working fine. But I have a focus issue as below.

When I check for validation and my focus on checkbox and now I am popping up dialog alert then focus is coming on "OK" of dialog popup and it is working fine.

But when my focus is on textbox and now I am popping up dialog alert then focus is not coming on "OK" of dialog popup.

***Code:***

```
$("#dialog-message").dialog({
    modal: true,
    height: 160,
    width: 350,
    //closeOnEscape: false, 
    buttons: {
        Ok: function () {
            $(this).dialog("close");
            if (focusElement != null && focusElement != "") {
                document.getElementById(focusElement).focus();
            }
        }
    },
    open: function () {
    }});
```

So I want to set focus on OK when I am alerting dialog and my focus is on textbox.

Answer (score 1):

You may try this to set the focus on `OK` button on load

```
open: function () {
    $(this).parent().find('button:nth-child(1)').focus();
}
```

[**DEMO.**](http://jsfiddle.net/heera/U5Bnd/1/)

Answer (score 1):

Add an id to the button and focus the button when the dialog opens:

```
$("#dialog-message").dialog({
    modal: true,
    height: 160,
    width: 350,
    //closeOnEscape: false, 
    buttons: [{
        id: "close-button",            // <-- set the id
        text: "OK",
        click: function() {
            $(this).dialog('close');
        }
    }],
    open: function() {
        $("#close-button").focus();    // <-- select the close button via the id
    }});
```

That works for me.